# Filter table data as your type

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 columns in a table, as shown below:
[image]

I want to filter rows as type in the text box above them.

The text boxes itself, optionally, use http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ to show the list of possible values as you type long.

Is there are a jquery tool I can use to achieve this?

If not how can i do that using JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout datatables examples

http://datatables.net

http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/FixedColumns/col_filter.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use String.match(regex) to do so.
Chosen seems reaaly nice, which features do you need more ?

Comment: Chosen will work for text boxes. i wanted to know if there was a jQuery plugin i can use instead of writing the code myself

Comment: I think you'll need to write some code anyway ^^ but look at http://datatables.net, it seems really good also =)